# create pdf with long lines, fit to pagewidth without wordwrap

Tags: pdf, text, latex, vector

i'd like to create a large pdf (not typical page size) with long lines, max ~1000 characters / line, where the page size and font are such that no lines need to wrap.

the intention is not for the text in this document to be readable when the full page is viewed on any reasonably-sized monitor -- instead the reader can zoom to individual portions of interest within the document.

i attempted this with a small font in latex, but no success.

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Do you want a really really large page or really really small font?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with pdflatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pdfpagewidth 200cm
\pdfpageheight 200cm
\textwidth 190cm
\def\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in
reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.} 
\begin{document}
\lorem \lorem \lorem \lorem
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks jouni -- this is great.

wondering if there's a way to "auto-scale" this, so that the width adjusts to fit the longest line without linebreaks, regardless of the length.

but this will do for now!